# REST API: Nested resource whose POST side effects create new (different) resources

Tags: api, restful-url, rest

I'm new to REST and trying to understand if the following approach is an accepted RESTful practise.

As a representative example, imagine in my domain I have a Route that is made up of a number of Legs. New locations can be added to a route, that create additional Legs in the Route. Another means of creating additional legs is selecting drivers. (The domain will create legs based on those the driver supports). So:

I can view a route, and a route and it's legs with the following resources:

```
GET /route/{route_id}
GET /route/{route_id}/legs
```

When adding legs to a route, I want to display a list of locations, that the user can select from. So I have implemented a locations resource. Locations are mostly static, and are provided from a separate system.

```
GET /route/{route_id}/locations
```

So the approach I wanted to take is:

```
POST /route/{route_id}/locations
```

When this resource is posted too (along with info like the arrival time etc. in the JOSN representation), it causes a side effect in the domain where new legs are created in the route.

For drivers it would be something like:

```
GET /route/{route_id}/drivers
POST /route/{route_id}/drivers
```

So after POSTing to:

```
/route/{route_id}/locations
```

The user would browse to:

```
GET /route/{route_id}/legs
```

And see the new legs.

Is this a viable approach to the above situation?

Another options would be:

```
GET /route/{route_id}/legs/locations
POST /route/{route_id}/legs/locations
```

Although conceptually this doesn't seem any different (the resources are just the same - the name of the URL is superfluous to REST).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have an answer to my own question, which is that the above approach is correct. After some reading of the books: "RESTful Web Services" and "RESTful Web Services Cookbook" (both from O'Reilly) I came across what they refer to as "factory" resources.

> "A POST request is an attempt to create a new resource from an
>   existing one. The existing resource may be the parent of the new one
>   in a data-structure sense, the way the root of a tree is the parent of
>   all its leaf nodes. Or the existing resource may be a special
>   “factory” resource whose only purpose is to generate other resources.
>   The representation sent along with a POST request describes the
>   initial state of the new resource."

From RESTful Web Services by Leonard Richardson; Sam Ruby

So essentially locations are a factory resource that creates legs.

Interested if anyone disagrees with my reading.